# Is there a way to show login error in Django?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, django-forms

I have a custom login page for my web. Upon keying the right account details, I can log in to my web. But if I key in wrong account details, it just refreshes the pages with the `username` and `password` 's textbox empty. Is there some way to show something like `'Username or Password is wrong'` as a error or message?

Within the login.html I have the following

```
{% if messages %}
{%for message in messages%}
<div class ="alert alert-success" role="alert">
{{message}}
</div>
{%endfor%}
{%endif%}

{% for field in form %}        
{% if field.errors %}        
{% for error in field.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
 <div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="align-middle pr-2">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                                class="bi bi-x-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                <path
                                                    d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM5.354 4.646a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708L7.293 8l-2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708L8 8.707l2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L8.707 8l2.647-2.646a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8 7.293 5.354 4.646z" />
    </svg>
   </div>
  <div class="align-middle"><b>{{field.label}}</b> - {{error}}</div>
 </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The following does not seem to do anything if the username or password is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add this in your template

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <p>username or password is wrong</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In any web application, we need to display notification messages to the end user after processing a form or some other types of his requests. To make this messaging system simple, Django provided full support to cookie and session based messaging for both anonymous and authenticated users.

This messages framework is capable of storing messages in one request and retrieving those messages in the subsequent request. Every message has a tag based on its priority(info,warning and error).

For more information click [here.](https://micropyramid.com/blog/basics-of-django-message-framework/)

Comment: I know this. But the problem is im not using any self coded view for this. I am using from ```from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views``` and ```auth_views.LoginView.as_view```